Conditionally show/hide Link columns in Telerik Report Designer 24
I'm working with Telerik Report Designer 24 and I have a scenario where I need to dynamically show/hide "Link" columns based on the value of another field, let's call it "Status". Specifically, I want these "Link" columns to be visible only when the "Status" field is set to 5. For all other status values, the "Link" columns should remain hidden.
Could someone please guide me on how to achieve this in Telerik Report Designer 24? I've looked through the documentation but couldn't find a clear solution for this particular requirement. Any help or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Could probably use the binding and bind the visible property to it conditionally that way
